# How do I forward my Gmail to my Facebook email address?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I have been trying to find a way to forward emails from my Gmail address to my Facebook email address. When I went to Gmail settings and tried to set up email forwarding from there, Gmail was unable to send a confirmation code to my Facebook address because Facebook rejected the email and returned a copy of the email with the confirmation link all X'd out.

How can I forward emails to my Facebook email address?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider retrying. It could be that you are not using the correct email address.

I received the following after trying

> phwd@gmail.com may now forward mail to phwd@facebook.com.

As well as a notice at the top after enabling forwarding

> You are forwarding your email to phwd@facebook.com. This notice will end in 7 days.[Review Settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop) [Learn more](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=1355567)

Also most of the mail will show up in your other folder so you will have to use "Action > Move to Messages" to train the filter so you can get notifications, for example on your mobile device instead of push mail.

I will let forwarding run for a few days and give updates if anything changes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to *Mail settings* and then click on [Forwarding POP/IMAP](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/fwdandpop).
2. Click on **Add a forwarding address**
3. A popup window will appear to enter the email address where you want the emails to be forwarded to. Enter your Facebook email address.
4. A new popup will appear to tell you that the confirmation code has been sent to your Facebook address.
5. Login to your Facebook account and go to your inbox and see the message. If the confirmation code is not there check other sections of your messages. When you do find the confirmation code, copy this code and go back to Gmail.
6. Enter the code copied in step 5 and then click on Verify.
7. Select the option **Forward a copy of incoming mail to**, and from drop down menu select the option which best suits you, by default it's **Keep a Gmail’s copy in the inbox** then
8. Click on **Save Changes**.

Now you will get notifications whenever you get email for this email address.

Comment: Please summarise the site you link to so that we can keep all of the information required for the answer here on site. If your answer isn't substantially different from the existing one then please reconsider posting it. There's no point in repeating the same information in two answers.

Comment: If you want to spam with your blog post, just copy the content across here next time and don't leave a link as the only sentence